# MissingTemplate Frustrating behavior

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am completing this [rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning)

Everything was going along smoothly even though im working on windows, until i hit the [partials section](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#sec-partials).

I pretty much copy pasted everything from the tutorial. I made sure that the underscore character in the partial filenames is an actual underscore.

I have placed the partials in the

```
app/views/layouts/
```

path as the tutorial suggests and included the

```
 <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
```

in my application.html.erb file. This results in the

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate in StaticPages#home 
Showing E:/ruby/my_projects/sample_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #9 raised:

Missing partial layouts/shim with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "E:/ruby/my_projects/sample_app/app/views"


Extracted source (around line #9):

"data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= render 'layouts/shim' %> #this is line number 9 
</head>
<body>
<%= render 'layouts/header' %>
```

I have tried placing the files directly in views folder as well as in the static pages folder.
I restarted the rails server multiple times during this process.

Anybody has any ideas?

Comment: what's the full path and filename of shim?

Comment: can you paste the application.html.erb or at least a chunk of it around and including line 9?

Comment: E:\ruby\my_projects\sample_app\app\views\layouts\\_shim.html.erb line 9 is <%= render 'layouts/shim' %> but its copy pasted exactly from the tutorial

Comment: Have you tried <%= render partial: "layouts/shim" %> ?

Comment: i did. It yields the same results

Comment: do you have the page in the views folder - presumably the index.html.erb or home.html.erb?

Comment: do you have a route set up to point to static_pages#home?

Comment: my application.html.erb (my page is in the layouts) folder. I tried to create a sub-folder called layouts and placed all the partials there but it didn't bring any results. I dont know if I have the route set up (how would i check that?) I know the website works fine without the partials

Comment: do you mean the  get "static_pages/home" in my routes.rb file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I guess its a ridicules mistake but it took me so long to figure it out. It should be obvious for me that windows hides extensions so after i misnamed my file the first time and tried to fix it (rename it) it already hid the `.erb` extension. So it had an `.erb.erb` extension and because of that it didnt work.

Thanks everyone that tried to help.